# Weird behaviour with kotlin/kotlin-coroutines and list of result pairs

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I'm working with kotlin/kotlin-coroutines and facing a weird behaviour with a List of kotlin.Result. Here is my code
snippet with example values to represent my issue:

```
val input = listOf("input_1", "input_2", "input_3")

// List<Pair<String, Result<ByteArray>>>
val asyncResults = input.map {
    async { it to
        runCatching { asyncCall(it) }
    }
}.awaitAll()

// name: String, result: Result<ByteArray>
asyncResults.forEach { (name, result) ->
    result.onSuccess {
        println(it)
    }
}

suspend fun asyncCall(str: String): ByteArray {
    // operate with string and return ByteArray
}
```

When I run my application I'm retrieving the following Exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: class kotlin.Result cannot be cast to class [B (kotlin.Result is in unnamed module of loader 'app'; [B is in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap')
    at MainBlockingKt$main$1.invokeSuspend(MainBlocking.kt:22)
    at kotlin.coroutines.jvm.internal.BaseContinuationImpl.resumeWith(ContinuationImpl.kt:33)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.DispatchedTask.run(DispatchedTask.kt:106)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.internal.LimitedDispatcher.run(LimitedDispatcher.kt:39)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.TaskImpl.run(Tasks.kt:95)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler.runSafely(CoroutineScheduler.kt:571)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.executeTask(CoroutineScheduler.kt:750)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.runWorker(CoroutineScheduler.kt:678)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.run(CoroutineScheduler.kt:665)
```

Why can I not use onSuccess or onFailure with the result variable? When I'm just printing the result it shows the
following content:

```
// name: String, result: Result<ByteArray>
asyncResults.forEach { (name, result) ->
    println(result)
}

Success(Success([B@7ea37dbf))
Success(Success([B@4b44655e))
Success(Failure(java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: <exception text>))
```

My result variable seems to be Result<Result<ByteArray>> instead of Result<ByteArray>>?? I'm really confused and didn't
find any solution on SO or on the web...

Comment: are you sure your code is exactly like this? Because for me it works fine

Comment: Yes it's exactly like in the question, i prepared the snippets for the question because it's proprietary code.

Answer (score 2):

I tried to reproduce your error. I believe I made a complete kotlin program with identical code. The following code works without any error, so I'm not sure what's wrong but maybe with this full code you can find your error:

```
import kotlinx.coroutines.*

suspend fun main() {
    GlobalScope.launch {
        val input = listOf("input_1", "input_2", "input_3")

        // List<Pair<String, Result<ByteArray>>>
        val asyncResults = input.map {
            async { it to
                    runCatching { asyncCall(it) }
            }
        }.awaitAll()

        // name: String, result: Result<ByteArray>
        asyncResults.forEach { (name, result) ->
            result.onSuccess {
                println(it)
            }
        }
    }

    delay(1000)
}

suspend fun asyncCall(str: String): ByteArray {
    delay(100)
    return ByteArray(1)
}
```

Comment: I'm copied your code and run it, but I'm retrieving still the same ClassCastException.....

Comment: @Oni1 hmm very strange. don't know if it is relevant. but I use kotlin 1.6.10 and `org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:1.6.0`

Comment: I'm using kotlin 1.5.10 and also 1.6.0 for the coroutines-core

Comment: @Oni1 i think that's it. I downgraded kotlin to 1.5.10 and I get the same exception as you. So maybe it's a bug in kotlin that got fixed in a later version. try upgrading to 1.6.10 and see if it helps :)

Comment: @Oni1 if you don't like to upgrade the minor version from 5 to 6, it seems that it's also already fixed in `1.5.32` so you could try that

Comment: Saved my day!!! After upgrading kotlin to 1.6.10 (and also 1.5.32 works fine) I don't get the ClassCastException anymore... Thanks! Do you have any idea which bug it is? I think it's interesting for my colleagues

Comment: @Oni1 no sorry, I have no idea. You can try search for it maybe in here somewhere https://kotlinlang.org/docs/releases.html#release-details if you click on `Release on GitHub` at a specific version it shows more details